# How to access all (including duplicate elements) of set in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates, set

## I want to access all elements of set in Python, also duplicate elements

```
s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 78, 6}

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Use a list instead? `s=[1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,78,6]`

Comment: @Ake - `s` is deduplicated as soon as it is created, so even `list(s)` doesn't 'get-back' the duplicates

Comment: Sets do not / cannot contain duplicates - by definition

Answer (score 1):

Sets by design have no duplicates. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> Python also includes a data type for sets. A set is an unordered collection **with no duplicate elements**. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set objects also support mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and symmetric difference.

If you want a data-structure which has a similar set of operations for intersection, union, etc, you can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) which is provided by the python standard libraries.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 78, 6])

# Iterate over unique items
for i in c:
    print(i)

# Iterate over duplicates as well
for i in c.elements():
    print(i)
```